# Running iPhone side by side with another iPhone

Tags: iphone, password, screen, unlock

I just bought a new iPhone to replace the one I dropped in water. The old iPhone works except for the screen, and I can't back it up via iTunes on my computer because I have a password on the old iPhone.

On another thread (see below), it said running the iPhones sides by side works, but I can't find anywhere that says how to do this. Please help - I have a number of texts I need to back up and have access to.

Suggestion from other thread:

> I think your best bet is to to run your iPhone side by side with another iPhone that is also set to lock. Now, by using the two phones side by side, you should be able to enter your passcode 'blind' using the position of the keys on the working phone as a guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally, put the phones side by side & using 2 fingers simultaneously, tap the same part of each screen at the same time, using the working screen as the guide & simply tapping 'blind' onto exactly the same place on the other screen at the same time.

That way, hopefully, both will be in sync as you tap in the unlock code, then work towards being able to back it up.